# Tortoise SVN unable to authenticate password

Tags: svn, passwords, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Ever since I changed my password Tortoise SVN will not authenticate.  Even though I can browse the repository through the Web interface with the new password fine, TSVN will not authenticate it.  We use the "free" version of VisualSVN Server and TSVN 1.7.6.

I tried clearing the stored password cache with no luck.  Other users dont seem to have a problem logging in on my machine, but I cannot log in on anyone elses.

Anyone familiar with this issue?

Comment: If you were using Basic Windows (AD) authentication, then the but has to be solved in VisualSVN Server 3.5.0: `Fixed: unable to authenticate using Windows Basic Authentication when a password contains non-ASCII characters.`. See https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v3.5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the "£" character from my new password allowed Tortoise SVN to then authenticate correctly.

Comment: Can confirm this was the issue for me too. Was behaving like it was an incorrect password, when in actual fact it does not support the £ character

Comment: Even nowadays that characters aren't possible, also with the § character isn't possible to login.
The errormessage: Authentication failed, no more credentials or we tried too many times.